# X32dbg Stepping through assembly, seems to get stuck on one line and not progress forward, even though the application continues to progress forward

Tags: assembly, dongle

I'm using x32dbg. Stepping through assembly, I get to the following instructions:

'''76B7CC12 | 8B4C24 54                | mov ecx,dword ptr ss:[esp+54]           |'''

If I continue to step through the assembly, the program continues to open and start up, but for some reason x32dbg stays on this line. What's going on here? There is not a breakpoint here.